# My service always getting Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord error in Kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a background service which is running in kitkat always throwing Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord message in the logcat. But in the previous versions of android my app is running smoothly without any issues.

also Sometimes my service is automatically killed in the Kitkat.

Comment: How many background services are you trying to start from your app?

Comment: check your `onHandleIntent` inside `IntentService`. Comment all your custom code. The try run again. It might be problem with code inside that

Answer (score 12):

This is caused by "Serialize running of background services" modification for ActivityServices.

> Implement #10744011: Serialize running of background services
>   Added some code to the activity manager to keep track of
>   services that are launching and limit the number that can
>   be launched concurrently.  This only comes into play under
>   specific circumstances: when the service launch is a background
>   request (so timing is not important) and its process is not
>   already running at a high priority.
>
> In this case, we have a list of services that are currently
>   launching and when that gets too big we start delaying the
>   launch of future services until currently launching ones are
>   finished.
>
> There are some important tuning parameters for this: how many
>   background services we allow to launch concurrently (currently
>   1 on low-ram devices, 3 on other devices), and how long we
>   wait for a background service to run before consider it to be
>   a more long-running service and go on to the next pending
>   launch (currently set to 15 seconds).

https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/9210bc85545f31973c957b5179e6a82d05f473c6

Comment: So is there any way to actually overcome this problem. I just want to run my service for sometime, but I am always getting this error "Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord error in Kitkat"

Comment: @nagamatu  So what's the implication of this framework change?  Is this a problem for developers to look out for?

Comment: @gaurav414u no, I didnt find anything.

Comment: If on a specific device: Does it help to set build.prop: ro.config.max_starting_bg to something bigger than 1 or 3?