# Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord Kitkat

Tags: android, service, android-4.4-kitkat

My app running a background service running in kitkat throwing: `Waited long enough for: ServiceRecord{42e8a230 u0 com.src.app/.ServiceName}` not always as mentioned in this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512469/my-service-always-getting-waited-long-enough-for-servicerecord-error-in-kitkat)

My app crashes one or two times in a day, and I am hoping this is the reason why my app crashes. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512469/my-service-always-getting-waited-long-enough-for-servicerecord-error-in-kitkat#answers-header) mention the cause of this issue but I can't understand how to fix this issue. I am sure my app not running the same service multiple times concurrently.

Any help should appreciate me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21512469/my-service-always-getting-waited-long-enough-for-servicerecord-error-in-kitkat

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you can try IntentService ,depending on the task you perform on your service presently.